# Pytorch：How to balance the backpropagation calculation with multiple gpus

Tags: pytorch

In order to balance calculation of loss backward, I not only calculate loss in forward() but also realese the loss backward.Here is my realease way.Is there any wrong?

```
 def forward(self, x, y=None, criterion=None, gpu_nums=1):
    x = self.task(x)
    if not y == None:
        loss = criterion(x, y)
        if gpu_nums > 1：
            loss /= gpu_nums
        loss.backward()
        return x, loss
    return x
```

Is my implementation correct?If not, hope you can provide the right way.This is meaningful for everyone.

Comment: Why don't you use `nn.DataParallel` instead? It handles multiple GPUs on its own. Check this out: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html#create-model-and-dataparallel

Comment: I have been using `nn.DataParallel` in fact. What I want to discuss is that how to balance loss calculation with `nn.DataParallel` being used. So I realese the loss calculation and backward in `Model.forward()`. And what I want to know is that `loss /= gpu_nums` is right or not to ensure weights' grad is right. If someone don't pay atttention to the loss calculation and backward balance, the `device_ids[0]` will afford more memory compared with other gpu devices.